# Is there a way to run ad-hoc commands instead of creating a recipe within a chef-solo ruby script?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm using chef solo with the following files.

**node.json**

```
{
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[testing]"
  ]
}
```

**solo.rb**

```
file_cache_path "/home/vagrant/chef"
cookbook_path "/home/vagrant/chef/cookbooks"
json_attribs "/home/vagrant/chef/node.json"

execute "testing" do
  command "echo hello"
end
```

Why doesn't the `echo hello` part of the **solo.rb** run?  Is it possible to run ad-hoc commands within **solo.rb**?

Or should **solo.rb** only be used to specify the path of **node.json** which would include a recipe for the ad-hoc command.  I'm trying to avoid creating a recipe for just a simple one-off command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run ad hoc Chef code, you can use [chef-apply](http://docs.getchef.com/ctl_chef_apply.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [the solo.rb config file](http://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_solo.html), but that is the **config** file for Chef Solo - you cannot execute recipe code inside that config file. If you want to execute a Chef recipe, you can add it to the run_list in the JSON file.